# How do I add a directory, or bulk, of users to Microsoft SQL Server permissions

Tags: sql-server, security, logins

I have a front end program in Visual Basic that is using SQL Server as a "back end". The only way I can get permission for login to use the SQL server is by adding each name or computer individually and this will take forever to update and maintain.

My question is how do I do this at the group level? I found two similar questions that are essentially asking the same thing and they can be found at the following links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server
- [Microsoft SQL Server v13 bulk add users from active directory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223187/microsoft-sql-server-v13-bulk-add-users-from-active-directory)

My problem is that these do not work for me. I get all the way to the end and when I click Ok nothing happens. Please reference the picture I attached to the post.

Do I need to add the directories in some other place before I can use the add button or am I missing something else?

[image]

The following picture is what I am trying to select.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

To finish the set up you must type the name of the directory into the check names box and click check names to confirm it. This seems intuitive but it is an easy step to miss. Please reference the pictures below, also my folder was named users, yours may be something else:

The first picture is before clicking the check names button
[image]

This picture is after clicking the check names button
[image]